Gitlab to Github Migration
We have a script runs on hourly basis to integrate Gitlab with serviceNow and LDAP, this helps us to manage Gitlab groups and permissions. Also integrated with OKTA for SSO.
ServiceNow Group Synchronization: A script or integration likely manages bi-directional synchronization between ServiceNow groups and GitLab groups. When a new ServiceNow group is created (or deleted), a corresponding GitLab group is created (or deleted) as well with the same name.
AD Group User Population: The script extracts users from the Active Directory (AD) group associated with a ServiceNow group. It then assigns user permissions within the GitLab group:
The owner of the ServiceNow group becomes the owner of the GitLab group.
Other members of the AD group become developers in the GitLab group.
For instance when the script run it will identify the new serviceNow group call S1 and create the Gitlab group with same name S1, also script identify the AD group attached to the S1 and call the LDAP to list out the users and owners. Now script will add these users as developer for S1 Gitlab group and AD group owner as Gitlab group owner.
Can this be possible in GitHub cloud platform?
Based on my understanding, GitHub Cloud doesn't have a concept directly equivalent to GitLab groups. Seems I need to integrate GitHub with serviceNow to create all serviceNow groups as orgnizations. Then, for each organization, I use ServiceNow data to retrieve the associated AD group details and add those users as teams within the corresponding GitHub Cloud organization.
Unsure if the above mentioned process works. Any pointers can help us with the migration.
